# Install Guest Additions on Kali Linux on VirtualBox 5 on Ubuntu

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox

I'm trying to install virtualbox guest additions for Kali Linux on Oracle VBox 5 as specified on the kali linux [page](http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-virtual-box-guest).

When I run:

`apt-get update`

`apt-get install -y virtualbox-guest-x11`

`virtualbox-guest-x11` has missing dependency `xorg-video-abi-19` which I can't find a way to install.

```
root@kali:~# apt-get install -y virtualbox-guest-x11
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-guest-x11 : Depends: xorg-video-abi-19
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

root@kali:~# apt-get install -y xorg-video-abi-19
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Package xorg-video-abi-19 is a virtual package provided by:
  xserver-xorg-core 2:1.17.2-1 [Not candidate version]

E: Package 'xorg-video-abi-19' has no installation candidate
```

Alternatively when I try the procedure described for older distros, I successfully install:

`apt-get update && apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

However after running `./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` I get the following:

```
root@kali:~# ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 5.0.24 Guest Additions for Linux............
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Removing installed version 5.0.24 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...
Removing existing VirtualBox non-DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
Removing existing VirtualBox non-DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel modules
The headers for the current running kernel were not found. If the following
module compilation fails then this could be the reason.

Building the main Guest Additions module ...fail!
(Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong)
Doing non-kernel setup of the Guest Additions ...done.
```

If anyone could provide a solution for installing VB guest additions that would be great.

**EDIT:**

After running apt-get `install build-essential dkms`

The 2nd error changes to:

```
root@kali:~# ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 5.0.24 Guest Additions for Linux............
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Removing installed version 5.0.24 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...
Removing existing VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Removing existing VirtualBox non-DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
Removing existing VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.

Removing existing VirtualBox non-DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel modules
The headers for the current running kernel were not found. If the following
module compilation fails then this could be the reason.

Building the main Guest Additions module ...fail!
(Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong)
Doing non-kernel setup of the Guest Additions ...done.
```

Comment: Run `apt-get dist-upgrade` then try it again

Comment: @Christopher I did as you said and I get the same errors. I had run `apt-get dist-upgrade` previously and when running the command now, I only installed a few things. I rebooted then ran `apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`, however it seems I'm at the newest version: 'linux-headers-4.8.0-kali2-amd64 is already the newest version (4.8.11-1kali1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.'

Comment: `build-essential is already the newest version (12.2).
build-essential set to manually installed.
Suggested packages:
  python3-apport
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dkms linux-headers-amd64`

Comment: @Christopher I get a different error for installing from CD. Check the edit.

Comment: Afraid not, I ran the commands and nothing new was installed. I tried running  ./VBoxLinuxAditions and get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked after I installed v5.1. of VBox and did a fresh install of Kali. Upgrading from 5.0 with 5.1 with Kali installed messed up the VM for some reason.